# SQL Server 2008 R2 Linked Server to another SQL Server 200r R2 select query error Invalid data for type "Numeric"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

we are having the following error message on a SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP1 linked server to another SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP2.  The error message is: Invalid data for type "numeric" and is happening intermittently.  It worked for couple months and re-appearing again.  Called Microsoft Support last July 2012, they haven't able to solve it either and we closed the case after it mysteriously disappeared.  All we did is just applied some Windows OS patches before the problem disappeared.  Now the problem is re-appearing.  The error message was from a simple query

```
select * 
from Sales_LinkedServer].sales.dbo.temp_sales_detail
```

However, this table contains over 2 millions records.  Tried and still failed using the

```
OPENQUERY: 
Select * 
From OPENQUERY ([Sales_LinkedServer],
'Select * 
From Sales.dbo.temp_sales_detamil');
```

Also, this is happening on our production server but the similar Dev server has no problem at all.